# Chrome slow, especially when unlocking computer

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I've been having a lot of slowness with google chrome. When I come to work in the morning, I unlock my computer.  I then try to browse in chrome.  I'll go to my already open tabs (won't be unusual for me to have 20 open) and they show blank pages.  If I leave the computer for a few minutes, it'll eventually re-render these tabs.  However, the computer will be really slow during the period.  I'm also experiencing intermittent slowness in chrome with going to new pages and opening tabs... but like I said it's very intermittent.  I have a really decent PC... any ideas what could be causing this?  Nothing jumps out while watching the chrome or windows task manager.

Comment: Have you already rebooted your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's answered very clearly [in another Q on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/9004/google-chrome-tabs).

Quoting:

> "In the fallowing scenario:
>
> have multiple tabs opened in Chrome, and don't use it for a while
>
> have many opened applications that trigger windows to send unused applications to swap file (run out of memory)
>
> When you return to Chrome, you will feel each tab recovering from swap slowdown. In other applications you will be delayed only once.
>
> You could call it a performance issue, but it's only a side-effect of the different process architecture."

Comment: Yeah took a closer look earlier and that was what was happening... running out of memory and paging it out......